# Which site is the best to ask about reinforcement learning?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, questions, machine-learning

Reinforcement learning is part of ML and I know ML is a good topic here. However, I know there is a data science and a computer science site (and maths etc). I was wondering, where would a reinforcement learning question be better to ask?

Comment: Sadly,proposal of ML and AI site always fail at Area51.

Comment: I think CV is most appropriate for such questions.

Comment: @WeiChing why did the ML site fail? is it because this one encompasses ML?

Comment: because data-science site and CV site .

Answer (score 16):

Reinforcement learning is on-topic here, and I hope our ML side grows as much as possible, so I hope you will ask it here.  However, you should consider the nature of the RL topic about which you want to ask.  For example, if you wanted to ask about the mathematical analysis of various (asymptotics and such), you may prefer to ask on math.SE, etc.

Comment: Also if your question is mainly about implementation, Computational Science SE might be appropriate as well.